# Python Bloomberg xbbg

Tags: python, pandas, bloomberg

I am having trouble running an extract using the `xbbg` package with the following function. It does not generate an error message but it returns an empty dataframe when a similar excel function works.

```
test=blp.bdp(tickers='SPX Index', flds=['INTERVAL_PERCENT_CHANGE'],calc_interval='1Q',start_date_override='2018-10-10')
```

It works well when I am running simple static function like this one:

```
blp.bdp(cusip_list, ['TICKER_AND_EXCH_CODE', 'Security_Name', 'GICS_Sector_Name'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date overrides for Bloomberg needs to be this format: `YYYYMMDD` - change `2018-10-10` to `20181010` should be good.

While `xbbg` is flexible with date formats, Bloomberg itself does have certain constraints.